# React router dom not render component

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-redux, react-router-v4, react-router-dom

[image: enter link description here]React Router will not render Route component unless page is refreshed
I can't find the reason why react is not rendering the component.

Comment: what about the `debugger`, did you try without it? did you try using component instead of renderer ?

Comment: Are you using Redux?

Comment: You might want to take a look at the following link https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/packages/react-router/docs/guides/blocked-updates.md

Comment: "debugger" is not creating problem here i added for check... yes i am using redux

Comment: i am using render in routes because there i am checking authentication check, can't use component here ....

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using `browserHistory` in the Router?

```
import { browserHistory } from 'react-router'; 

<Router history={browserHistory}>
...
</Router>
```

Comment: yes i am using this as import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Switch } from "react-router-dom";